# VS2010 : afxcw.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___wargv

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc

I receive the reported error when compiling my dll under VS2010.

uafxcw.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___wargv
uafxcw.lib(appcore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argc

Settings seems to be corrected; that is :

Use of MFC set to :  Use of MFC in a Static Library

Runtime Library set to :  Multi-threaded

The dll is a directshow filter (Entry point : DllEntryPoint@12). All linked static library are compiled with the same settings, but I can't remove this error.
Preprocessor settings are :  WIN32;NDEBUG;_WINDOWS;UNICODE

Someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

From [You receive an "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___argc" error message when the MFC library and the CRT library do not match in debug/release or in static/dynamic in Visual C++](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/166504)".

When the MFC and CRT (C Run-Time) libraries do not match in debug/release or in static/dynamic, you will get this error.

**Resolution:**

To change the type of C Run-Time library used by an application or DLL, go to the Build/Project settings property sheet and switch to the C/C++ tab. On the C/C++ page, choose the "Code Generation" category. Change the value of the "Use run-time library" listbox. Pay careful attention to make this specific for each configuration; only one configuration, such as "Win32 (80x86) Debug," should be selected when you change this value.
Debug, shared library MFC applications - "Debug Multithreaded Dll."

Release, shared library MFC applications - "Multithread Dll."

Debug, static library MFC applications - "Debug Multithreaded."

Release, static library MFC applications - "Multithreaded."